# Generating Permutations of the given array using Backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, arraylist, backtracking

I was trying this problem where we need to find the permutations of the elements in the array.

This is the [leetcode problem no 46](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/). The issue I've faced is that I'm not able to output the `ans` it just keeps returning a blank `ArrayLists`:

*Code:*

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) 
{
    List<List<Integer>> fans = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> fmap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i: nums){
        fmap.put(i, fmap.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
    }
    int n=nums.length;
    List<Integer> ans=new ArrayList<>(n);
    dfs(1, n, fmap, ans, fans);
    return fans;
}

public void dfs(int cs, int ts, HashMap<Integer, Integer> fmap,List<Integer> ans, List<List<Integer>> fans)
{    
    if (cs > ts)
    {
        fans.add(ans);
        return;
    }
    for(Integer val: fmap.keySet())
    {
        if (fmap.get(val) > 0)
        {
            fmap.put(val, fmap.get(val) - 1);
            ans.add(val);
            dfs(cs + 1, ts, fmap, ans, fans);
            ans.remove(ans.size() - 1);
            fmap.put(val, fmap.get(val) + 1);
        } 
    }  
}
```

*Output for the test case* `[0,1]`:

```
[[],[]]
```

The actual output should be:

```
[[0,1],[1,0]]
```

When I'm checking the "potential answer" inside the recursive method, I am able to see the correct answer. I mean, if I print the output in the `dfs` method, it shows the correct answer:

Change in the code:

```
 if (cs > ts)
    {
        fans.add(ans);
        System.out.println(fans);
        return;
    }
```

Now it's printing the value of `fans`:

```
[[0, 1]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

But these values are not being updated in the `fans` and the returned value comes up blank.

I read someone mention this same issue, but it was for Python, and the solution in that case was to do a deep copy of the list.

I'm not sure how to do that in Java.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to generate a list of permutations, you don't need a `Map`. You've only introduced redundant actions, which are not useful anyhow. If you doubt, add a couple of print-statements to visualize the map state it will always contain the same key with the value `1` (all numbers in the input are guaranteed to be unique) and it has no impact on the result.

#### Source of data for generating the Permutations

Besides the fact that attempt to utilize the `HashMap` as the source of data for generating permutations isn't working because of the bugs, it's also not a good idea because the order iteration over the *keySet* of `HashMap` is not guaranteed to be consistent.

As the uniform mean for storing the numbers that haven't yet been applied in current permutation, we can use an `ArrayList`. In this case because there will be no duplicates in the input (see the quote from the *leetcode* below), we can use a `LinkedHashSet` instead to improve performance. As explained below, a removal of elements will happen at before making every recursive a call, and removal from an `ArrayList` has a cost of **O(n)**, meanwhile with `LinkedHashSet` it would be reduced to **O(1)**.

> **Constraints:**
>
> - 1 <= nums.length <= 6
> - -10 <= nums[i] <= 10
> - All the integers of nums are **unique**.

#### Generating the Permutations

Each generated *permutation* should be contained in **its own list**. In your code, you've created one single list which is being passed around during recursive calls and eventually every recursive branch adds the same list to the resulting list. Which obviously should not happen.

You see, the result is being printed as `[[],[]]`. It seems like a list containing two lists, but in fact they refer to the same empty list.

And this list is empty because every element that was added to it, is being removed after performing a recursive call:

```
ans.add(val);
... <- rursive call in between
ans.remove(ans.size() - 1); // removes the last element
```

> if I print the output in the dfs method, it shows the correct answer:

Actually, it's not correct. If you take a careful look at the results, you'll see the nested lists are the same `[[1, 0], [1, 0]]`.

The final result is blank because all recursive calls are happening between each value being added and removed (see the code snippet above). I.e. removal will be performed in revered order. That would be the last lines to be executed, not the `return` statements. To understand it better, I suggest you to walk through the code line by line and draw on paper all the changes done to the `ans` list for a simple input like `[0, 1]`.

Instead, you should create a **copy** of the list containing not fully generated *permutation* (`answer`) and then add an element into the *copy*. So that the initial *permutation* (`answer`) remains unaffected and can be used as a template in all subsequent iterations.

```
List<Integer> updatedAnswer = new ArrayList<>(answer);
updatedAnswer.add(next);
```

And you also need to create a **copy** of the source of data and remove the element added to the newly created *permutation* (*answer*) in order to avoid repeating this element:

```
Set<Integer> updatedSource = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
updatedSource.remove(next);
```

*Sidenote: it's a good practice to give meaningful names to methods and variables. For instance, names `cs` and `ts` aren't informative (it's not clear what they are meant to store without looking at the code), method-name `dfs` is confusing, DFS is a well-known algorithm, which is used for traversing tree or graph data structures, but it's not related to this problem.*

#### Building a recursive solution

It makes sense to keep the recursive method to be `void` to avoid wrapping the result with an additional list that would be thrown away afterwards, but in general it's more handy to return the result rather than accumulating it in the parameter. For performance reasons, I'll keep the method to be `void`.

Every recursive implementation should contain two parts:

- **Base case** - that represents a simple edge-case (or a set of edge-cases) for which the outcome is known in advance. For this problem the *base case* would represent a situation when the given *permutation* has reached the size of the initial array, i.e. the source will contain no element, and we need to check whether it's empty or not. Parameters `cs` and `ts` that were used for this check in the solution provided in the question are redundant.
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where recursive calls a made and when the main logic resides. In the *recursive case*, we need to replicate the given answer and source as explained above and use the updated copies as the arguments for each recursive call.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
    Set<Integer> source = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int next: nums) source.add(next);
    
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    permute(source, new ArrayList<>(), result);
    return result;
}

public static void permute(Set<Integer> source, List<Integer> answer,
                           List<List<Integer>> result) {
    
    if (source.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(answer);
        return;
    }
    
    for (Integer next: source) {
        List<Integer> updatedAnswer = new ArrayList<>(answer);
        updatedAnswer.add(next);
        Set<Integer> updatedSource = new LinkedHashSet<>(source);
        updatedSource.remove(next);
        permute(updatedSource, updatedAnswer, result);
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] source = {1, 2, 3};
    List<List<Integer>> permutations = permute(source);
    for (List<Integer> permutation: permutations) {
        System.out.println(permutation);
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rKh)

Comment: I really understand the points you made regarding my solution here  are some of the thing i thought of while doing the solution:  1: Use of Hashmap : this was done because if you look at the Permutation 2 problem (leetcode 47) it contains duplicate values ,in my mind i was thinking of making this solution work for both of the cases(duplicates and non duplicates) .

Comment: 3. theres still this thing im not sure about i change the code to make a deep copy of the ans ArrayList in my base and then the code worked perfectly    `if(cs>ts)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<>();
            temp.addAll(ans);
            fans.add(temp);
            return;
        }`  now this is working perfectly and im getting the correct answer , what you explained that the "list is empty because every element that was added to it, is being removed after performing a recursive call" should be true in this case but the thats not the case.

Comment: And for the naming of the variables the cs specifes the current spot you're on and ts are the total no of spots that is for 1,2,3 ts=3 and we increase cs for every element we take i.e cs=1->2->3.  A link to the updated solution : https://pastebin.com/AD74AcW2(This works for both leetcode 46 and 47).

Comment: @IshmeetSingh *im not sure about i change the code to make a deep copy* - it' s already making a copy. Have a look at the code carefully. Deep copy - means to make a copy of the **mutable** object nested inside another object. `Integer` is **immutable** you only need to create a copy of the list based on the existing list `new ArrayList<>(myOldList)` which is already done in the code above.

Comment: @IshmeetSingh Regarding the parameters `cs` and `ts` - you can use them but they are redundant. Regarding the names, see [*Java Naming Conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and [*Self-documenting code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Comment: @IshmeetSingh *Permutation 2 problem (leetcode 47)* - `HashMap` doesn't guarantee the consistency of iteration (which is important), `LinkedHashMap` does, but my suggestion is: first, try to solve the *problem 47* using an `ArrayList` to store the numbers from which permutations should be constructed. And then try with `LinkedHashMap`, it will require more elaborate code.